# Turning and if and elif statement into numpy form

Tags: python, numpy, loops, indexing, range

I want the code to print true if `PC_list` array crosses the `Upper` or `Lower` boundary. I am essentially trying to convert the vanilla python code to numpy version so it is faster. The if functions look for if the `PC_list` crosses the upper or lower numpy arrays. I get an index out of border error when the numpy.select function is run though. `IndexError: index 25 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 25`

numpy version:

```
PC_list = np.random.rand(1,25)
Upper = np.random.rand(1,25) 
Lower = np.random.rand(1,25)

#Configs
Lower = 0.2  #Lower and upper boundary values 
Upper = 2
number = 10000   #used for calculations with stand deriv and linear reg
position_value = 0 
conditions= [
    ((PC_list[PC_x_list+1]<lower[Boundary_x_list+1]!=PC_list[PC_x_list]>lower[Boundary_x_list]|PC_list[PC_x_list+1]>lower[Boundary_x_list+1]!=PC_list[PC_x_list]<lower[Boundary_x_list])&(position_value==0|position_value==2))|((Boundary_x_list==Boundary_x_list[-2])&(position_value==0|position_value==2)),
    ((PC_list[PC_x_list+1]<upper[Boundary_x_list+1]!=PC_list[PC_x_list]>upper[Boundary_x_list]|PC_list[PC_x_list+1]<upper[Boundary_x_list+1]!=PC_list[PC_x_list]>upper[Boundary_x_list])&(position_value==0|position_value==1))|((Boundary_x_list==Boundary_x_list[-2])&(position_value==0|position_value==1))
    
]

choices = [
    print("lower cross"),
    print("upper cross")
    
]

np.select(conditions, choices, default = 'NA')
```

Vanilla python version:

```
for i in range (len(PC_list)):
    if ((PC_list[i+number-1] < lower[i-1] != PC_list[i+number] > lower[i] or PC_list[i+number-1] > lower[i-1] != PC_list[i+number] < lower[i]) and (position_value==0 or position_value==2)) or ((i == len(PC_list)-number-1) and (position_value==0 or position_value==2)):         
        print("lower cross")    
    elif ((PC_list[(i+number)-1] < upper[i-1] != PC_list[i+number] > upper[i] or PC_list[(i+number)-1] < upper[i-1] != PC_list[i+number] > upper[i]) and (position_value==0 or position_value==1)) or ((i == len(PC_list)-number-1) and (position_value==0 or position_value==1)):
          print("upper cross")
```

Comment: Can you explain in exhaustive detail what you think those long conditions are doing? Some of that operator precedence does not look quite right.

Comment: Why do you do `Upper = np.random.rand(1,25)` only to set it to a constant a couple of lines later?

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: Look at `choices`.  I expect it is `[None,None]`.  `select` is not a conditional operation. Rather it returns an array whose values come from `choices`.  You need to test this code step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the `np.select` that's raising the indexing error?  You may need to show the actual traceback.

But I think you have to wrong idea about how `select` works.  It is more like a generalization of the 3 argument `np.where`.  Let me illustrate:

```
In [165]: x=np.arange(5)
In [166]: conditions = [x<2, x>3]
In [167]: choices = ['A','B']
In [168]: np.select(conditions, choices, default='C')
Out[168]: array(['A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B'], dtype='<U1')
```

It returns an array with values take from `choices` and `default`.  It does not "run though" anything.

If I construct a `choices` as you do:

```
In [169]: choices = [print('A'), print('B')]
A
B
In [170]: np.select(conditions, choices, default='C')
Out[170]: array([None, None, 'C', 'C', None], dtype=object)
```

The print occurs in [169] when choices is constructed. Nothing happens in the `select`, except selecting from one of the values of `choices` - which are both `None`.

```
In [171]: choices
Out[171]: [None, None]
```